# Should I, for any reason, allow a Super Admin to see the users' password through the UI?

Tags: user-interface, permissions, admin, roles

Currently I am developing an application with 3 roles: 1 for customers, 1 for the company employees and another one for a Super Admin.

Is it a good practice to allow Super Admin users to see/edit the users' passwords through the UI? Or should it only be modified directly through the DB?

**UPDATE**: I am using asp.net membership provider and MySQL. Therefore, there is a table in the DB called **my_aspnet_membership** which stores two fields: Password and PasswordKey. The field PasswordKey seems to be the encrypted password. However, the Password field is stored in plain text. So, can anyone tell me why this is designed in this way if it is not a good practice? Thank you all for your responses!

**UPDATE**: For those who asked if it really stores the password in two different fields:

[image]

Comment: This tells me you are storing your passwords in plain text (to be able to see the pass)? It comes down to how much a liability the admin's are, but usually, edit (well set a new password) but not see is the way most applications go.

Comment: Suggest this should go on IT Security more than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No user should be allowed to see the Plaintext password of any other user whatsoever. The password must be encrypted atleast if not hashed even in the database. 
You MAY allow the super admin to change any user's password, but allowing him to see it in plaintext is taboo.

EDIT: Are you absolutely certain the password field stores the password in plaintext, while there exists another passwordkey field? Because, it sounds similar to a 'salt' mechanism to me. Where, the password is first encrypted with one key, and then re-encrypted with the passwordkey field.

EDIT 2: I am now almost absolutely certain that your database is using a salted password. Salted passwords are often used to increase the security level of the database. For more information on salt, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Yeah.. it now seems more than likely that the database is using a salt mechanism. I way I have seen it used is, password = md5(md5(pass) + salt) where pass is the plaintext password entered by the user.

Answer (score 3):

Your password should not be stored un encrypted inside your database and as such, shouldn't be visible to users of the UI nor the database.

As for whether it should be modifyable, sure.

In this case the password should be re-generated through user or administrator request. Again, this should be encrypted in the database. My preference would be to auto generate the new password for the user rather than have an administrator type it themselves.

Given this, the only way to change the password directly in the database would be to encrypt it first before insertion. It's quicker to do this through an UI that deals with the encrypting.

**UPDATE**

In answer to your update, you should specify in your web.config that the password format be hashed:

```
<providers>
<add [...]
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
/>
</providers>
```

as outlined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

Comment: There are a few times where unencrypted passwords are a must, certain challenge-response protocols for instance!

Comment: @ewanm89 - this would be the sign of a poorly thought out protocol. A better one would be one whose C/R is based on a hash of the original password instead of the actual password.

Comment: @mah I quite agree, but go read the standards like DIGEST, non of them do because then the protocol authors would have to think about weaknesses with hashing or encrypting a hash and such. So they just avoid it by storing in plaintext or reversible encryption.

Comment: Maybe it's time we drew up such a protocol spec that can handle a hashed preshared secret with knowledge that it doesn't weaken the underlying cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

There is never a reason to allow someone to see a password they do not own, under any circumstance.

Update for the OP Update: Of course I have no way to know why your DB was designed like this. Thinking optimistically, it contains the plain password so that if a user forgets their password it can be mailed to them -- a bad excuse, but an unfortunately common one. A better alternative is to have the system mail them a freshly generated temporary password -- one which works only to allow setting of a permanent password (and does not destroy the current password until the change occurs).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It makes sense. Just to let you know that it is not that "MY" DB was designed like these, but the "ASP.NET Membership Provider" was. In terms of functionality it allows the app to send the password to users through email. So, it might be the reason as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should always save passwords encrypted. Therefore you don't have any possibility to show the superadmin the password of another user.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever store password as is in any database. Always use a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to  save the password.

Answer (score 0):

You should save all passwords encrypted in DB.. Not in plaintext!!